# Best way to define dynamic mapping index fields in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have some couple of objects which contains dynamic keys. How can i define the mappings so that the search query gets optimised.

e.g.
I have following nested and object type fields

```
"similarities": [
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key3": "value1",
    "key4": "value2"
  }
]
"entity": {
  "version": "SO",
  "Non-Commerical": "GGP"
}
```

For result, i need all documents where `entity` contains `GGP` no matter what the key is.
Can you help in defining the mappings and search query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) for `entity.*` with [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) to another field, let's say `entity_values`. Then you just need a `match` query against `entity_values` which now contains all of the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the key-value in entity dict is dynamic and there can be multiple ket-values and which i don't have each key names. Does `copy_to` works in that case?

Comment: Yes if you define a dynamic mapping it will automatically get applied to all keys inside the `entity` and "copy" all values into the accumulator field.